# Changing ToggleSwitch ON-Color Dynamically in Universal Windows Application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have A Toggle Switch in my page, when its status is **ON** ,its color is same as my theme color. First I need to change its color when is **ON**.

Second, I want to change color dynamically in C# code, by calling function.

I can change background color with following code but I could not find a way to change its **ON-Color**

```
public void ChangeTogSwColor(Windows.UI.Color _color)
{
    mySwitch.Background = _color;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by overriding the `ToggleSwitch`'s default style.

First, go grab the style from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299159.aspx) and put it in your `App.xaml`. After that, locate an element called `SwitchKnobBounds` -

```
<Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" 
            Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOn}" 
            Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOn}" 
            StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchOnStrokeThickness}"
            Width="44" Height="20" Opacity="0" RadiusY="10" Grid.Row="2" RadiusX="10" />
```

This is the element that represents the *border* and *background* of the `ToggleSwitch`. To change the background color, you can simply replace `ToggleSwitchFillOn` with whatever color you like.

However, since you also want to update it dymanically in code, you should have the `Fill` property to bind to an existing dependency property of the `ToggleSwitch` control (otherwise you need to extend the control and add your own dependency properties).

I personally would use `Background` and replace `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` with `Background="Transparent"` from the top level `Grid` 'cause I never realy needed to give the control a different background color other than *transparent*.

Then, your `Rectangle` would look something like this -

```
<Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" 
            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOn}" 
            StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchOnStrokeThickness}"
            Width="44" Height="20" Opacity="0" RadiusY="10" Grid.Row="2" RadiusX="10" />
```

Finally, you can set the `Background` color of the *On* state directly in XAML or in code.

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="MyToggle" Background="Green" />
```

or

```
MyToggle.Background = Colors.Red;
```

Comment: Would you please tell me more details about where should I locate **SwitchKnobBounds**?

Comment: See the link I attached to the answer? Go to the link and search for the name "SwitchKnobBounds".

Comment: hi @JustinXL, the link "here" you posted in the answer just goes to a general "XAML styles" description page. Don't know where to grab the style